# My new Logitech MX KEYS keyboard STOPPED responding - I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: keyboard, logitech

My new Logitech MX KEYS  keyboard STOPPED responding - I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS .

Also:
I tried the command :
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
I went through the prompts... and  tried to chose my  keyboard model but I did NOT see my Logitech MX KEYS  on the shown database list .

Please help! Many Thanks in advance.